# Closing Profiler without stop it first

Tags: sql-server, profiler

Closing Microsoft SQL Profiler without stop it first.
By doing that, is it keeping the process alive and affecting the SQL performance?

I am asking this because I am wondering why the utility warns me when I am trying to do so.

Answer (score 4):

For any future references - according to MS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/close-a-trace-window-sql-server-profiler closing the trace window stops the associated trace.

Comment: This was my experience while using SQL Profiler 2018, I accidently closed the profiler and found this thread. I was able to verify in the database that the trace was stopped after I closed it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the trace is still running if you close the tool without stopping it. If you've paused the trace, it's not running, but it still exists on the server. Much cleaner to stop it and clean up after yourself.

In any case, [you should try to avoid using Profiler anyway, especially against production](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events). Use a [server-side trace](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/272/profiler-and-server-side-traces/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), [extended events](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2155/getting-started-with-extended-events-in-sql-server-2008/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) or a 3rd party tool.

Comment: So if i close the utility before stop the running trace, when the process will stop? how can i get a list of that processes and how do i stop them?

Comment: Look in sys.traces where is_default = 0. If you've done this multiple times (or if a lot of people are running traces all the time), it may be hard to figure out whose is whose, but you should be able to observe properties like start date. Once you've identified an abandoned trace id, you can stop it using [sp_trace_setstatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176034.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned using Trace is somewhat old-school, slows down the server (depending on what you're tracing), very difficult to pin-point events that are at the crux of your problem, and there are better ways now (post 2012).

I suggest EE, if you don't have SQL Server Enterprise edition (cannot do proper Audits down to table/row level), which was my issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

But to answer your question, I am sure closing down SQL Profiler only stops a trace. It doesn't delete it.

You can see what's running by:

```
--List all SQL Traces 
SELECT * FROM sys.traces
```

And then re-start the trace directly:

```
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus 2,1 --where '1' is Start, '0' is stop and '2' is delete it
```